# How to add road labels using ggplot and ggmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm creating maps for different areas and I've managed to get almost all layers to work and look like ArcGIS. The only place I'm stuck is adding the labels to the major road network. I can get the lines to draw properly but the shape file doesn't have a specific x y notation, it's start/end. Apologies for not reproducible code as I can't upload the actual shape

```
# Load Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggmap)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)


# Green-Red Pallete for DAs
pal <- c("#006837", "#1A9850","#66BD63","#A6D96A","#D9EF8B",
         "#FEE08B","#FDAE61","#F46D43","#D73027","#A50026")

# Load Shape Files
Road <-readOGR (dsn = "C:/Users/Shape Files", # dsn = data source name 
                layer = "MajorRoads") # layer = file name

DA_2015 <- readOGR (dsn = "C:/Users/Shape Files",
                    layer = "DisseminationAreas")

# Fortify Shape Files Areas -----------------------------------------------------

DA.f <- DA_2015 %>% fortify (region = "DAUID")%>%
  left_join(DA_2015@data, by=c("id" = "DAUID" )) 

# Create Map -----------------------------------------------------------

map <- ggplot () + 
  geom_path(data = DA.f,
            aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id)) +
  # Add colours to DA
  geom_polygon(data = DA.f,
               aes (x = long, y = lat, group =  id, fill =  csi_bin)) +
  # Add gradient scale to DAscolors
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal)  

RoadLayer <- geom_path (data = Road,
                        aes (x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                        fill = "grey50", 
                        alpha = 0.5)

map + RoadLayer
```

[image]

How do I add the labels for the roads?

EDIT:

Here's a sample of a map I did in ArcGIS.

[image]

Comment: `geom_text`? You might have to calculate another data set to get the mean x, y coordinates for the road names

Comment: That won't work as it'll center on the road vs. rotating like ArcGIS.

Comment: ggplot doesn't have anything to do that out of the box. You could add a basemap or layer that just has the road names or you could switch to the leaflet package.